# Single distributed system to handle large and small transactions

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, distributed-computing

I have a kafka topic. The producer publishes 2 kinds of messages to this topic. Large messages which take more time to process and then small or fast processing messages. The small messages are of large volume (80%). The consumer receives these messages and sends these messages to our processing system. Our processing system have set of microservices deployed in Kubernetes environment as pods (which provides option to scaling).

I have to get the overall processing time as 200ms per transaction and system processing speed of (with scaling) to 10000 tps.

Now what is the better way to design this system in such way that small messages are processed with no blockage from large messages. Or is there a way to isolate the large messages in same channel without impacting processing small messages. Looking for your valuable inputs.

I have put a sample control flow of our system

[image]
.

The one option which I have is that consumer diverts the large message to one system and small messages to other system. But this doesn't seem like a good design and nightmare to maintain 2 systems with same functionalities. Also this could lead improper resource allocation.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume large message and small messages can be processed out of order. Otherwise small messages will have to wait for large message and there is no parallelization possible.

I will also assume, you can not change producer to write large messages to another topic. Otherwise, you can just ask producers to send large messages to a different topic, with lesser number of consumers, so large messages will not block small messages.

Ok, with above two assumptions, following is the simplest solution:

1. On the consumer, if you read a small message, forward it to the message parser as you are doing today.
2. On the consumer, if you read a large message, instead of forwarding to the message parser, send it to another topic. Let's call it "Large Message Topic"
3. Configure limited number of consumers on the "Large Message Topic" to read and process large messages.

Alternatively, you will have to take control of commit offset, and add a little more complexity to your consumer code. You can use the solution below:

1. Disable auto commit, don't call commit on consumer after reading each batch.
2. If you read a small message, forward it to the message parser as you are doing today.
3. If you read large messages, send them to another thread/thread pool on your consumer process, that will forward it to the message parser. This thread pool processes in coming messages in a sequence, and keeps track of last offset completed.
4. Once in a while, you call commit with offset = min (consumer offset, large message offset)